# How to find colour variations between one and another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, colors, gradient

If I have colours `#FF0CB6` and `#EC9CF4`, how could I find 10 variations in between them (like a gradient would do) and eventually have them in an array?

Similar to what this website does: http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/

Does anybody know how to approach this problem?

Comment: Break the hex values in to their RGB component colours, then find equidistant values between the extents and convert those all back to hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'RainbowVis-JS' and get the hex colour code between two color hex code.

```
var numberOfItems = 8;
var rainbow = new Rainbow(); 
rainbow.setNumberRange(1, numberOfItems);
rainbow.setSpectrum('red', 'black');
var s = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfItems; i++) {
    var hexColour = rainbow.colourAt(i);
    s += '#' + hexColour + ', ';
}
document.write(s);
```

Comment: I went with the plugin eventually, was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

To use plain javascript, you need two things. First you need to convert the the HEX colors to integers. I named the function `colorStrToIntArray`:

```
function colorStrToIntArray(color) {
    // strip '#'
    if (color.length == 4 || color.length == 7) {
        color = color.substr(1);
    }

    // for colors like '#fff'
    if (color.length == 3) {
        var r = parseInt(color.substr(0, 1) + color.substr(0, 1), 16),
            g = parseInt(color.substr(1, 1) + color.substr(1, 1), 16),
            b = parseInt(color.substr(2, 1) + color.substr(2, 1), 16);

        return [r, g, b];
    } 

    // for colors like '#ffffff'
    else if (color.length == 6) {
        return [
            parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16), 
            parseInt(color.substr(2, 2), 16), 
            parseInt(color.substr(4, 2), 16)
        ];
    }

    return false;
}
```

On the second step you just calulate the difference between the integers. And voila, there are your colors:

```
function calculateSteps(color1, color2, steps) {
    var output = [],
        start = colorStrToIntArray(color1),
        end = colorStrToIntArray(color2);

    var calculate = function(start, end, step) {
        return (start + Math.round((end - start) * (step / (steps / 2))));
    };

    for ( var i = 0; i < steps; i++ ) {
        var color = [0, 0, 0];

        color[0] = calculate(start[0], end[0], i);
        color[1] = calculate(start[1], end[1], i);
        color[2] = calculate(start[2], end[2], i);

        output.push(color);
    }

    return output;
}
```

The code could possible be shorten, but it is working. :)

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/t7ozs42o/2/)**

---

Some time age I've written a little script, [called js.colorGradient](https://github.com/eisbehr-/js.colorGradient), for myself. It calculates the color in a range from `0%` to `100%`. It allows you to even use more then two colors to crate ranges. It may be not exactly what you are looking for, but feel free to change it as you like to use it.

```
var gradient = new ColorGradient(["#FF0CB6", "#EC9CF4", "#0F0", "#00F"]);

for( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ) {
    var color = gradient.getHexColorAtPercent(i);
    $("#demo").append('<div style="background: ' + color + '">');
}
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/cwtokcf7/1/)**

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!